# Using categories in my php variable?

Tags: categories, php, parse

How do I get the if statement below, to return TRUE and therefore return my string "Africa is in this array"? Note: template is set to parse on INPUT (I cant use output for this template)

```
 <?php 
    $entryregion="{categories show_group='4' backspace='2'}{category_name}, {/categories}";
    $entryregionArr=(explode(',',$entryregion));
    print_r($entryregionArr);
    echo "<br />" ;
    if (in_array('Africa', $entryregionArr)) {
        echo "Africa is in this array";

    }
    ?>
```

the above `print_r($entryregionArr);` prints an array that looks like this. `Array ( [0] => Africa [1] => South Africa [1] => Durban [1] => )` I *think* I want it to look more like this  `Array ( [0] => Africa [1] => South Africa [2] => Durban )` where Durban is in the 2nd key and the last key id deleted, but I am not sure why or how to do this. I have tried `parse='inward'` in the category tag.  I had a recent suggestion through this site to use  the explode() function and I am grateful because it has shown me that this is where my error is. Well, one step at a time. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It's my personal advice not to mix up the EE tags with PHP code. There may cause issue because of "PHP Parsing Stage" sometime.

In your case, you can use PHP code like:

**EDITED:**

```
$this->EE =& get_instance();
    $res = $this->EE->db->select('cat_name')->where('group_id', 4)->get('categories')->result_array();
    foreach ($res as $r)
    {
        $entryregionArr[] = $r['cat_name'];
    }

    if (in_array('Africa', $entryregionArr)) {
        echo "Africa is in this array";
    }
```

I hope, it would help you.

Comment: Thanks for reading, you have the right idea! This looks great at a glance, but for some reason it doesn't work (the $ee() breaks the page). Its within an entry tag and php needs to be parsing on input. I like the idea of not mixing ee with php tags, because you bang-on, I **have** had a lot of issues with parsing stages. I had a little progress with this function _in_array_r_ I found at this link [link](https://gist.github.com/rianrainey/4263778), but still not returning true. Ahhh! any more ideas, I would love to try, I am at my end on this one?

Comment: I edited the code. Please try and share your further findings...

Comment: Thanks, no luck. Still renders my page as code instead of parsing it. I am not sure I understand the complexity of the 1st line. Does it refer the entries within the entries tag?

Comment: Check if template preference have "Allow PHP?" as "Yes".

Comment: Yep, and **allmost** all the other php I have used on the page. You may understand the comment that I just placed under Robson Sobral's suggestion. Some of the php functionality works, other functionality does not. I would love to take the ee/categories out of the equation like you suggest to avoid parsing being an issue. I made mistake in my original question - **php parsing is on INPUT** not Output.

Comment: I now have it returning "Africa is in the array" using your code above FANTASTIC! Thank you. it worked after i switched the output to input than back again. I can even use '$_GET["region"]' to use what is input by the user dynamically. This is great, one last clarification ... It shows the statement 'Africa is in this array' even when it is not a category in that entry. Can I change the second line so that it is only looking at each entry individually? or should that be what it's doing now?